# Is there any implementation of std::binary_search will return true while search for 4 in {8, 4, 6, 2}?

Tags: c++, stl, binary-search

I read a question below in a text book which said 1 is a possible output.
I tried it in VS and g++, both give out 0.
Is the text book wrong?

```
int t[] = { 8, 4, 6, 2 };
deque<int> d1(t, t + 4);
cout << binary_search(d1.begin(), d1.end(), 4) << endl;
```

Comment: This is a bit unclear, by the way. Does the book claim that 1 is a possible output, or does it ask whether it is?

Comment: binary_search return bool

Comment: the book claim that 1 is a possible output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text book is right; the question is a theoretical one, even trying multiple implementations cannot help you falsify the claim (the most you can do is to find an implementation that *proves* the claim).

`binary_search` requires a sorted array, if you pass an unsorted one you are going into undefined behavior land, where everything can happen, including finding your number and returning `true`.

For example, an implementation that happens to use the second position in your array as first guess, or that switches to linear search for a short container may easily do this. Hell, even something like this is a perfectly conforming implementation:

```
template<class ForwardIt, class T>
bool binary_search(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value) {
    // check the first two values just because
    for(int i=0; i<2 && first != last; ++i, ++first) {
        if(!(*first<value) && !(value<*first)) return true;
    } 
    first = std::lower_bound(first, last, value);
    return (!(first == last) && !(value < *first));
}
```

---

That being said, what is more interesting is that not only 1 is a possible output, but 5 or 42 are possible as well, although IMO less likely than "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"; this to say: undefined behavior is *really* undefined (and I've seen many times libstdc++ `std::sort` crash the program if passed a comparison operator that didn't define a strict weak ordering).

Comment: Good answer! Thank you!Text book is evil.

Comment: That text book is actually quite smart if it's educating about undefined behavior quite from the start 